# Memory leak in C++ application

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, stdlist

I've already tried a thousand times to find the *damn* memory leak in this snippet, yet i'm just miserably failing... i'm learning memory allocation and these things and i was never able to make a program that would completely free it's memory yet...

I'm calling a for loop to allocate 140 Contato_s structures and put them into Agenda std::list. Then i call another for loop to delete all 140 contacts using RemoverContato and the respective code... Windows doesn't reports a single Kb of free'd memory!

```
struct Contato_s
{
    int Codigo;
    std::string Nome, Numero, Email, Apelido;
};

std::list<Contato_s*> Agenda;

void CriarContato(std::string Nome, std::string Numero, std::string Email, std::string Apelido) // Add a contact to the list
{
    Contato_s *temp = new Contato_s; // Criando um contato temporario

    temp->Nome = Nome;
    temp->Numero = Numero;
    temp->Email = Email;
    temp->Apelido = Apelido;
    temp->Codigo = Agenda.size()+1;

    Agenda.push_back(temp); // Adicionando o contato a lista
}

int RemoverContato(int Codigo) // Delete a contact from the list
{
    for (std::list<Contato_s*>::iterator i = Agenda.begin(), e = Agenda.end(); i != e;)
    {
        if((*i)->Codigo == Codigo)
        {
            delete (*i);
            i = Agenda.erase(i);
            return 1;
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)!

--Edit

Okay, that's how i'm trying to destroy the contacts:

```
for(int i=0; i<140; ++i)
    {
        if(RemoverContato(1+i) == 0)
            std::cout << "Fail removing contact " << i << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Contact " << i << " removed" << std::endl;
    }
```

(Ofc i always get "Contact X removed" and not fails at that part, so the contact is being found, in theory)

Comment: Well, are you calling `RemoverContato` for every element in the list? If you don't show how you're calling this code then there's not much we can tell you (other than that `std::list<Contato_s*>` instead of `std::list<Contato_s>` is unnecessary bordering stupid).

Comment: You need to show how you are calling `RemoverContato`. 9

Comment: Nothing you've said suggests that the memory is leaked. The physical memory is managed by the OS and always available for re-use if needed elsewhere. The virtual memory is per-process, and so can't be "returned". I think the error is just in your expectations -- expecting a process to return virtual memory to the system (which makes no sense since virtual memory is per process).

Comment: Lose the raw pointers, use smart pointers instead.

Comment: The idea is to learn memory allocations using raw pointers, so i see no point in just using some higher-level abstraction here :)

Comment: @wingleader : Putting unowned objects into a standard collection by their addresses is _not_ something to practice, it is something to always avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that each `Contato_s` has a unique `Codigo` (does that mean ID? I will call it an ID). It is possible that more than one `Contato_s` can share the same ID since you base the ID on the current size of `Agenda` (say you added two contacts, removed the first one, then added another one... both these contacts will have the same ID of `2`). Your removal technique will only remove the first matching ID, letting the other ones remain. You should go through all contacts and check all IDs before returning success or failure in `RemoverContato`.

Comment: Thanks, but i just checked and all the IDs are unique, this would mess up when creating and deleting multiple times though, so thanks, now based the Codigo creation to be *really* unique, but even then the leak persists.

Comment: How did you establish that the memory has leaked?

Comment: Uh using some observation on Task Manager *and* sysinternals VMMAP, i used also the string counter in vmmap and it reports an always-growing number of strings when calling create-destroy repeatedly

Comment: Can you paste the code that leaks then? There's no code to create or destroy anything here, just code to add and delete.

Comment: Oh, by create and destroy, that's what i meant. The "CriarContato" function gets memory by the new operator and the "RemoverContato" one (tries to) destroy the allocated memory by delete'ing it...

Comment: All of that code is fine. The problem, if there is one, is in code you're not showing.